# position background image center bottom with some offset

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I would like to position to the bottom of a background image but give it some vertical offset.

Lets say

Same way we can do:

```
.img{
     background-position: 5px center; /* top + 5px */
}
```

I tried to:

```
.img{
     background-position: -5px center; /* bottom - 5px ?? */
}
```

But the image won't even be visible

**How can I achieve this?** (without knowing the height of the element).

- So far I fixed it applying padding (size of image) and margin (offset) to the element with `postion:bottom center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using :before and :after you can achieve the result(use exact location of the sprite image.)

```
.img{
    position: relative;
}

.img:after {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -5px;
    content: '';
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: -16px;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.img:before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    content: '';
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: -16px;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: -15px -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `CSS2`, but with `CSS3`. Using `background-position` you can give a `position` or `negative` offset.

You can do something like:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dCKsZ/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat bottom -10px right -20px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

**[Browser compatibility list](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-image)**